# No me aparecen los Acentos-Ñ en mi Página Web publicada en el Hosting Infinityfree

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Anoche publiqué una Página en Infinityfree y no me está mostrando los acentos y ñ's del lenguaje español que están en los campos de la base de datos.
[image: Página web publicada]

Ya revisé el cotejamiento de phpMyAdmin de Infinityfree y está en MyISAM utf8_general_ci, por lo cual no debería haber problemas.
[image: Base de Datos con cotejamiento MyISAM utf8_general_ci]

Si alguien me pudiese orientar, se lo agradecería.

Comment: Tenes el meta tag utf incluido en tu codigo html?

Comment: Lucas se refiere a `<meta charset="UTF-8">` en el `head`?